# Azure Service Principal - Terraform - Error when refreshing state

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm working on a Terraform project in which I setup several Azure resources.

One of these Azure resources is a service principal (linked to an app registration) which I use to deploy my Terraform code in a CI/CD pipeline via Github actions.

When developing locally, I use `az login` to authenticate, but occasionally I'm receiving an error for the Terraform app service principal. Most of the times, when I re-run `terraform apply` the error is not raised. Sometimes the error persists for several `terraform apply` calls.

```
 Error: Retrieving Application with object ID "fe2b93b7-e26c-402c-ab4f-87e3695c1f45" with module.app_registrations.azuread_application.terraform_app on ../modules/app_registrations/terraform.tf line 56, in resource "azuread_application" "terraform_app": 56: resource "azuread_application" "terraform_app" { ApplicationsClient.BaseClient.Get(): Get "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/b859b851-97d8-4dc2-bf56-f2a5bc5c494b/applications/fe2b93b7-e26c-402c-ab4f-87e3695c1f45": http: RoundTripper implementation (*retryablehttp.RoundTripper) returned a nil *Response with a nil error
```

I'm having a hard time to understand why I'm able to generate this service principal using my user credentials via Terraform, but am receiving this retrieval error when refreshing the state of the same service principal. When I'm deploying the Terraform code via Github Actions, which uses the service principal to authenticate, this retrieval error is never raised.

Anyone can point me in the right direction?

I've already added the `Application administrator` role to my user credentials and added the `Application.ReadWrite.All` role to the Terraform service principal. Above error when refreshing the state using user credentials via `az login` persists.

Comment: Please add the error as text to the question.

Comment: Added the error as text!

Comment: Ok. if you are applying from local then try adding your user (the one you are 'terraform applying' with) into owners of Service principal.

Comment: This is already the case

Comment: This particular error message is reporting a "should never happen" case from the Go programming language's `net/http` library, so this seems like a bug in either `hashicorp/azuread` provider or in the underlying SDK it's built with. I would suggest opening a bug report issue in [the provider's repository](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azuread), where hopefully the provider team can find the bug and fix it. Once they know what the cause of the bug is they may be able to suggest a workaround to use until the fix is released.

Comment: I have a hunch that your request is timing out in a way that the underlying SDK isn't handling well (e.g. [there's a codepath which returns a nil error without checking if the response is set](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azuread/blob/09dba057f143cfccd62ee78a3013c5d62dca23e5/vendor/github.com/manicminer/hamilton/msgraph/client.go#L62)), but if that were true then I'm not sure what I'd suggest since you can't control how slow or fast your network connection is. 